# Why can't Tomcat find Java JDK or JRE?

Tags: tomcat, installation, xampp

When starting Tomcat in the XAMPP Control Panel v3.3.0 it says:

> Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1 Make sure you have
> Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free Check the
> "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information

When I go to page localhost:8080 it says:

> Hmmm.... Can't reach this page. localhost refused to connect.

I was expecting the message:

> [Tomcat] Status change detected: running

I have java installed and I don't believe there are port conflicts.

- PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx java -version
- openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS,
  mixed mode)

There are no log files in the Tomcat log folder.

Comment: This is running on Windows 11 Pro.